# soap object or property not found with SoapClient php

Tags: php, soap, soapfault

I have a strange mistake

Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'BA' property in *** (PATH)

But when I add in object "$RI2->BA = 0;" another error is:

Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] mkres: Parameter 'BA' not found in *** (PATH)

What I have to do?
thanks for your attension...

Comment: We would need a bit more information. Do you use a WSDL file, if yes, what does it look like. What does the rest look like?

Comment: OK, sure. Code is little bit large. I write client path for WSDL. 
Let me add few URLs with code...
functions and types output
[link](https://np7.ru/soap_debuging/tf.txt)
PHP 
[link](https://np7.ru/soap_debuging/php.txt)
WSDL
[link](https://np7.ru/soap_debuging/xml.txt)

Comment: SOAP server is running on Windows 10. I tested about 10 website sever configerations from apache 2.2 & php 5.4 up to apache 2.4 php 8.0

Comment: If you work with PHP5.4 and higher, I would stick to `__construct`, not `function TResInfo2`. Probably doesn't help with the problem at hand, but doesn't hurt either way. As for your actual issue...

I would start with [SoapUI Open Source (free)](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui/) and compare your PHP classes to what SoapUI receives.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok I will try SoapUI. And construct. Bot ask me to add links into the question topic?